# How do i find if its a repeating playlist?

Tags: c#, class

I need to find if the playlist is repeating. From my below code pls help to suggest a solution.
A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to null.

```
using System;

public class Song
{
    private string name;
    public Song NextSong { get; set; }

    public Song(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public bool IsRepeatingPlaylist()
    {
        if(this.name == NextSong.name)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Song first = new Song("Hello");
        Song second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");

        first.NextSong = second;
        second.NextSong = first;

        Console.WriteLine(first.IsRepeatingPlaylist());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing here?

Comment: Would you not need a collection song to be able to work this out? I would make a `Playlist` entity which contains a `List` of songs? You could then run some iterative logic to work out if there is a loop.

Comment: @AvinashReddy above code doesn't work. If playlist repeats, starting songs can be skipped

Answer (score 9):

This would appear to be equivalent to checking for cycles in a linked-list, so we can simply use [Floyd's "Tortoise and Hare" cycle detection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection):

```
public bool IsRepeatingPlaylist()
{
    var tortoise = this;
    var hare     = NextSong;

    while (tortoise is not null && hare is not null)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(tortoise, hare))
            return true;

        tortoise = tortoise.NextSong;
        hare     = hare.NextSong?.NextSong; // Twice as fast.
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here's some code that tests a playlist where the end of the play list loops back to a song about halfway through the playlist:

```
static void Main()
{
    Song start = new Song("1");
    Song curr  = start;

    Song halfway = null;

    for (int i = 2; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        curr.NextSong = new Song(i.ToString());
        curr = curr.NextSong;

        if (i == 50)
            halfway = curr;
    }

    curr.NextSong = halfway;
    Console.WriteLine(start.IsRepeatingPlaylist());
}
```

Comment: Can you give a brief explanation of this line "hare     = hare.NextSong?.NextSong;"  I have not ever seen a "?" in a statement like that.  What does it do?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff If the first `NextSong` is not null it will use it to dereference the second (`NextSong.NextSong`)  - but if it is null, it will return null instead. This is [the null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Thank you!  I did not know that could be written that way.

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean isRepeatingPlaylist() {
    Song next = this.NextSong;
    while (next != null) {
        if (next.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return true;
        }
        next = next.NextSong;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try and refrain from posting code-only answers. Giving an explanation as to how/why your code may solve the problem is always more useful than just posting code. In this instance, it doesn't answer the question the OP posted, as they were asking for _any_ previous song, not only the next song.

Answer (score 1):

> If playlist repeats, starting songs can be skipped.

To respond to this condition we need to use collections to register every song to ensure that aren't no circular playlist at the medium.

The use of HashSet is to ensure that our script is runing fine on a large playlist.

```
public bool Contains (T item);
```

The time complexity of this method is O(1).

```
public bool IsRepeatingPlaylist()
{
    var playList = new HashSet<Song>(){this};
    var song = this.NextSong;
    while (song != null) {
      if (playList.Contains(song)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        playList.Add(song);
        song = song.NextSong;
      }
      
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsRepeatingPlaylist()
    {
       var first = this;
       var second     = NextSong;

       while (first is not null && second is not null)
       {
         if (ReferenceEquals(first, second))
            return true;

        first = first.NextSong;
        second     = second.NextSong?.NextSong; // Twice as fast.
       }

       return false;
      
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a list for playlist songs. Before adding a next song to list, check if song is not null and if it already exist in list.
If null, not a repetitive playlist.
if doesn't exist, add to list and continue the logic.
If exists, its repetitive playlist.

```
public bool IsInRepeatingPlaylist()
{
    List<string> songsList = new List<string>();

    songsList.Add(this.name);
    Song thenext = this.NextSong;

    while (thenext != null)
    {
        if (songsList.Contains(thenext.name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            songsList.Add(thenext.name);
            thenext = thenext.NextSong;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```